# Terms to differentiate between internally-visible and user-visible errors

Tags: coding-style

In my code I often need to differentiate between messages intended for logging and those displayed to users.  I'm looking for a terse term for naming variables and methods that indicates a user-readable message.  I've tried "userReadable", "userVisible", etc, but they all feel too verbose, especially when combined with more details like "fileUserReadableError".

**E.g:**

```
fileLogError = "Error 123 occurred writing file /x/y/z";
fileUserReadableError = "We couldn't save your kitty picture, sorry";
```

Is there a better term?  The latter especially is a mouthful (fingerful, whatever)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sparse description the two errors can be internally identical with the difference being made by the locus of catching. To be more concrete:

```
def write_photo(photo, path):
    try:
       open(path, 'w')     # can throw OSError
       ...
    except OSError:
       logging.error("cannot write path", path)
       raise

def save_kitten(kitten):
    try:
        write_photo(kitten, '/x/y/z')
    except OSError:
        print('We couldn't save your kitty picture, sorry')
```

Obviously this model is Python-like because it has a well constructed exception mechanism. But you can read it as pseudo-code. The point is that there are two levels of operation, the internal (`write_photo`) and the user facing (`save_kitten`). The same error can be interpreted in two different ways depending upon what level the fault happens at. The concept of logging and re-raising allows one fault to be handled at two different levels of description.

Implicit here is that the fault really doesn't change its contents; the lone `raise` just re-throws the same exception. But the same fault does have different interpretations which are a feature of the level of detection. Adding another error type is needlessly redundant when each level knows who it is communicating with.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details.  I'm not looking for an answer to a specific problem.  This is a question about the best terminology to use when naming variables and methods.